# manipulate strides in tensorflow and/or theano

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, theano

In numpy, you can trick methods to be applied on sliding windows by changing an array's shape and strides, for example:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.arange(20)
r=5

y = numpy.ndarray(
    buffer=x.data,
    shape=(x.shape[0] - r + 1, r),
    strides=(x.itemsize, x.itemsize),
    dtype=x.dtype
)
print(x)
print(y)
x[4] = -1
print(x)
print(y)
```

https://ideone.com/SjdtrB

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 4 5 6]]
[ 0  1  2  3 -1  5  6]
[[ 0  1  2  3 -1]
 [ 1  2  3 -1  5]
 [ 2  3 -1  5  6]]
```

This saves memory and it's calculation time is constant.

Is this also possible in tensorflow or theano? Does any of these frameworks use strides in their internal representation?

Comment: The theano docs say on their welcome page: "**tight integration with NumPy** – Use *numpy.ndarray* in Theano-compiled functions." Is that what you are after?

Comment: Most of us perform that kind stride manipulation via `as_strided` which is buried in `lib.stride_tricks`.  It saves memory, until numpy is forced to make a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj The idea would be to use strides tricks as preprocessing, but end up with 'flat' classification labels. In this case, to have a MFCC (preprocessing-)layer for audio data.

Comment: @kazemakase I would like to do it in the tensorflow-space, not the numpy-space.

Comment: `lib.stride_tricks` is numpy, not tf or theano. I want this operation in tensorflow or theano.

Comment: @Herbert did you figure out a way to do sliding windows in tensor flow?